# Is it possible to execute JavaScript script in post-build action in Jenkins?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to execute JavaScript script after ending of build. This script should use npm packages. Installed plugin as I have is:
`post-build actions`. I've found something like execute script with option: `add generic file script`. If I give here path to .`js` script, will it work? Where should I place this script?

I can not check it easily because I do not have full control of this Jenkins instance.

Comment: The short answer is that you use the Node command, eg. `node /some/where/index.js`.  However, I'm not sure how the paths work out with Jenkins specifically, so hopefully someone else can provide that in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add you script to your npm `package.json` [scripts section](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) and run it like:

```
post {
  success {
    script {
      sh "npm run my-happy-script"
    }
  }
  failure {
    script {
      sh "npm run my-sad-script"
    }
  }
}
```

Also you can select which directory to run from with the `dir` command in your script block:

```
script {
  dir("lib/another/directory") {
    sh "node some-script.js"
  }
}
```