# Can I stop Jenkins jobs per the user who triggered it?

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins CI/CD dry run job that each developer can trigger. The question is, can each developer have permissions to stop/abort only his flows which he triggered or Jenkins doesn't support it?

Comment: Short answer: not likely. What is your security/authorization model?

Comment: How come jenkins doesn't support it?... it sound like a legit request

Comment: Because typically people trust their co-workers to do the right thing. As I asked, what is your [security/authorization model](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/managing-security/#authorization)? We work on teams who own products/applications, we use RBAC (marrix-based) authorization, based on roles, not people. We do not rely on individuals, rather team members acting in a role. Can you imagine otherwise? A CI/CD environment and "Oh, sorry, Dave's on vacation. Yes, I understand the system is haywire and must be fixed now, but you know people!".

Comment: Now, if you are aaking, "As a user with multiple jobs running, how can I quickly and efficiently stop only the jobs I triggered?", That can probably be achieved using a groovy-based script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lowest level of authorization is project-based security via the [Matrix Authorization Strategy plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-auth/) with *Job*: *Build*/*Cancel* and *Run*: *Delete*/*Replay*/*Update*.

You could use the [build user vars plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-user-vars-plugin/) together with the [Build Name and Description Setter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-name-setter/) to add the `${BUILD_USER}` to the build's name and/or description (with ☑️ *Set build name before build starts*) so that each dev knows which build to abort in case.

See also [How to get the BUILD_USER in Jenkins when job triggered by timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36194316/1744774).

To restrict the build history to the currently logged on user set the build name to `#$BUILD_NUMBER - Started by $BUILD_USER` and see my user script [Jenkins - Restrict build history to current user](https://gitlab.com/gerib/userscripts/-/blob/master/jenkins/Jenkins%20-%20Restrict%20build%20history%20to%20current%20user.user.js):

[image: Current user]

[image: Build History for current user]

Comment: Ok, but its still means user can abort by mistake other user job, right?

Comment: @arielma Right. A possible workaround could be using the above and a userscript that checks `<div id="buildHistory" ... >` and removes `<tr class="build-row ... " ... >` of not current users.

Comment: @arielma Done. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Not sure I understood how to use it on existing job. where I should put the script in case I have pipeline script? I've found this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62333631/11705021